# How to call RESTful Web Service in ajax?

Tags: ajax, html, web-services, restful-authentication

I'm trying to use Restful Web Service for currency conversion by using Ajax. Here I'm unable to parse or read data from xml file which is generated by the Restful webservice, please do look into my code and help me out.

**Code:**

```
<html> 
<head> 
    <script>
        var xmlHttp
        function showCust()
        {
            // alert("function Called");

            xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            //  alert("function Called");
            //var fromCurr = document.getElementById("name");
            var fromCurr = f1.elements[0].value;
            var toCurr = f1.elements[1].value;
            // alert("function Called");
            //alert(fromCurr + " " +toCurr);
            var url = "http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx/ConversionRate?FromCurrency=" + fromCurr + "&ToCurrency=" + toCurr;
            alert(url);
            xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);//it will call 'CustomerDetails' servlet 
            // alert("function Called");
            xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = stateChanged;//this is userdefined method which will fired based readyState property 
            xmlHttp.send();
        }

        function stateChanged()
        {
            // alert("function Called");

            //check whether the response is completely loaded or not? 
            if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4)
            {

                var str1 = xmlHttp.responseText;
                alert(str1);
                //var myObject = eval('(' + str1 + ')');
                //var text = '{"name":"Sivarmayya","email":"smadhupada@miraclesoft.com","phone":"9000387222"}'
                var users = xml.getElementsByTagName("double");
                alert(users);
                var user = users[0];



                //var obj = JSON.parse(str1);
                //document.f1.mail.value=obj.mail; 
            }
        }
    </script> 
</head> 
<body>

    <form name="f1" > 
        From Currency:&nbsp; <input type="text" title="enter from currency"  id="name"/><br> 
        To Currency:&nbsp; <input type="text" title="enter to currency"  id="name1"/></br>
        <input type="submit" value="Go" onclick="return showCust()">
        Result:&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="mail" /><br> 
    </form> 
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Although you haven't provided what kind of error you're hitting, I'd assume your problem is that your browser blocks CORS request: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Comment: I didn't get any error. The problem is i cannot get the data from xml file which is generated by using specified url..

Comment: how to enable CORS of a browser by using ajax

Comment: Do your homework, google it! The keywords `enable cors` give a lot of relevant results right on the first page. Anyway, you can start at http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Comment: I got a solution to enable cors in Internet Explorer browser by doing the following:

Comment: i.e You can add a trusted site in IE via the Tools | Internet Options | Security tab. Then you can set the security for trusted site via the Custom level | Miscellaneous section. You'll see that, by default, the "Access data sources across domains" option is set to Prompt. However, Prompt is unsatisfactory because it will interrupt any current application that is running with a message box, asking the user to confirm that they want access to the service. Instead, set the option to Enable.  But I didn't get a solution to enable CORS in other browsers...............